# Using BeautifulSoup to parse XML with tags that contain colon

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I was struggling a bit to parse XML that I got using BeautifulSoup and although I've read the documents, I can't seem to get it to work properly with the way my XML is set up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="/static/atom.xsl"?>
<feed xmlns:s="server url here">
    <!-- Feed elements>
    <entry>
        <!-- Other Elements -->
        <content type="text/xml">
            <s:dict>
                <!-- Other keys. -->
                <s:key name="sid">DATA I WANT HERE</s:key>
                <!-- Other keys. -->
            </s:dict>
            <!-- Lots of other dicts here. -->
        </content>
    </entry>
    <! -- Other entries -->
</feed>
```

My goal is to obtain the data from all the `s:key` with attribute `name` that has a value of `sid`. (i.e. All `s:key` have a `name`, but only one per `<entry>` is of type `sid`.

How do I print out all the text between the relevant `s:key` that is of type `sid` in my data?

What I've tried is:

```
print(tree.findAll('key', {'name'}))
```

as well as:

```
for elem in tree.feed.entry.content.dict.key:
    print(elem)
```

but obviously these are flawed and do not work properly as I want them to.

How do I accomplish what I would like to obtain?

Comment: btw, you don't need beautifulsoup for xml. beautiful soup is useful if the input may not be perfectly valid like some web pages. xml documents are usually perfect and can be parsed by directly: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: @balki Good to know, however I was having trouble with using element tree properly and soup seemed a bit easier to understand/work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
elements = soup.findAll("s:key", {"name" : "sid"})
for lele in elements:
    print(lele.text)
```

Output :-

```
DATA I WANT HERE
```